# Merging the Data from Different workbook into main workbook for a particular sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I want to merge a worksheet content named "Task tracking" from 3 different workbooks named Sub WB1, Sub WB2 and Sub WB3 into single Main Workbooks Task tracking worksheet. Please help.

There are 4 workbook in total with 12 worksheets in each.

Main Workbook
Sub WB1
Sub WB2
Sub WB3
I want to merge the data from "Task Tracking" (Worksheet name) from Sub WB1, Sub WB2 and Sub WB3 into Main Workbook using a Consolidate button in the main workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, try this AddIn.  this will do what you want.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm

Here is a screen shot of the UserForm that you interact with to control everything.

[image]